# Sync Data between clients and server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, server, synchronization

I'm newer to web design and I'm making a super simple website that a few friends of mine can use when they play DnD, it's meant to display health values that can be changed and update in real time.

As I mentioned: I'm newer to web design. Does anyone have a good recommendation of where to begin when it comes to syncing data between clients and the server? When someone clicks a button to increase or decrease a value, how would I get that change to reflect on each client's browser?

Here's my current guess. Would it be a good idea to use JSON files to shoot data in between clients and the server? I'm only expecting one person to be messing with values at a time. I've started looking into JSON but I'd like to get a second opinion.

I'm looking for the simplest way to accomplish this. I'd like to stay away from something that may require more knowledge than I currently have though I do understand that I may need to do a lot more learning in order to learn this. Thanks a ton in advance for your time!

EDIT: Here's my code to read from the JSON file. It works.

```
setInterval(function(){
   $.getJSON('json/file.json', function (data) {
   console.log(data);
   document.getElementById("entityOneHealth").innerText = "Health: " + data.health1;
   document.getElementById("entityTwoHealth").innerText = "Health: " + data.health2;
  });
}, 1000);
```

So I can get it to read from the JSON file now, all I need is to figure out how to save changes to the values and store them/overwrite the json file so it can be updated across all clients. What's the best way to go about this?

EDIT 2:
After doing some research it looks like this should do something similar to what I need, but it gives me a "not well formed error". Javascript below:

```
var rawData = {
"health1": 4,
"health2": 6
};

$.ajax({
   type : "POST",
   url : "some.php",
   data : {
    json : JSON.stringify(rawData)
   }
});
```

And my PHP file:

```
$json = $_POST['json'];

if (json_decode($json) != null)
{
  $file = fopen('json/your_array.json','w+');
  fwrite($file, $json);
  fclose($file);
}
else
{

}
```

Any ideas why it wont work?

Comment: Sounds like you want to have a server that is able to do 2 things. 1. To accept POSTs with values and write them  to a store (could be in memory, a file or a DB). 2. Allow GETs that will query from the store whatever the current values are. To keep all of the clients in sync, you can have them periodically make get requests to get the values (polling) or you can use something like websockets to push changes from the server to all clients whenever a value is changed (push). JSON is an ideal content type for representing the data. Please research and come back with sample code so we can help

Comment: @DvideBy0 Thanks so much for the help! Using GETs I've gotten the server to read from the JSON file and update across clients. My research tells me that PHP is the only way to actually write to a JSON file, is that correct? I'm rather confused with what I've been reading about POSTs and PHP, where would you recommend I start?

I've edited the original post to contain a sample of my GET code.

Comment: @DvideBy0 I posted some code I found and rewrote to fit my site, is what i have what I'm looking for, and if so what did I do wrong? I have a basic understanding of PHP now that I've done a bit of research on it but I'm still confused for the most part.